# UI Mode and switchType attributes in UI Components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Just learning the Richfaces UI components. I see in some of the UI components one attribute **Mode** that uses one of the three values 'ajax', 'server', 'client'. I checked the documentation. But I didn't find any proper explanation for these.

And one more is the switchType attribute. I didn't understand the explanation for this as well.

Can someone please explain me these two.

Thanks

Comment: what's your JSF and RichFaces version?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - JSF 2 and RichFaces 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes `mode` are used to specify the tag component how it should acts when an action is executed over it:

- Server (default value). The controls are rendered by doing a request to the server. The action is executed in the server side, there's no ajax included to execute the action, similar to click an `<h:commandButton />`.
- Ajax. Similar to `server` value but everything is done through an ajax call, similar to click an `<a4j:commandButton />`.
- Client: There's no action for this type of mode. The controls are all rendered in the client side.